# Oracle Transform rows into column and combined duplicate rows

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I'm new to Oracle DB. I'm not sure if it possible to do this. Basically I have a query:

```
SELECT location,properties,value FROM table_usa
```

that returns this output:

[image: Current output]

Somehow, I want to transform the latitude and longitude into their own column and also combine the initial duplicated rows. Desired output:

[image: Desired Output]

Is this even possible?

Comment: Did the answers solve your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `oracle` **11g** (and above) [`pivot`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#CHDCEJJE) is the *most versatile* tool for this task.

> The pivot_clause lets you write **cross-tabulation** queries that rotate
>   **rows into columns**, aggregating data in the process of the rotation.

**Source**

```
 LOCATION   |PROPERTIES |   VALUE  
 -----------|-----------|--------
 Texas      | Latitude  | 21.391 
 Texas      | Longitude | 54.12  
 Detroit    | Latitude  | 24.23  
 Detroit    | Longitude | 54.23  
 New York   | Latitude  | 24.239 
 New York   | Longitude | 55.5
```

**PIVOT Select**

```
select *
  from (select Location, Properties, Value 
        from table_usa)
pivot(
   max(Value)  
   for Properties in ('Latitude' AS LATITUDE,
                      'Longitude' AS LONGITUDE)
   )
order by LATITUDE;
```

**Results**

```
LOCATION    | LATITUDE  |LONGITUDE
------------|-----------|---------
Texas       | 21.391    |54.12 
Detroit     | 24.23     |54.23            
New York    | 24.239    |55.5
```

Comment: Yes this actually solve my question. Thanks! I have another question tho. Let say I have a situation (very rare but it happen) where my value is: 
`Texas | Sheriff | Abruzi`
`Texas | Sheriff | NULL`
`Detroit | Sheriff | Scofield`
`Detroit | Sheriff | NULL`

How do I get it to be:

`Texas | Abruzi`
`Detroit | Scofield`

If I used Max, I will get `NULL` for Texas, and if I used Min, I will get `NULL` for Scofield. Is there any trick to get handle this situation?

Comment: Hi, as requirements change, you should open a new question posting your current data and code

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle 11g you can try PIVOT ( see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html).

In previous versions, that should work:

```
select   location,
         max(decode(properties, 'Latitude', value, null)) latitude,
         max(decode(properties, 'Longitude', value, null)) longitude
from     table_usa
group by location
```